# Confluent Kafka Rest returning 40403

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have deployed the Confluent Kafka Rest Proxy 3.3.x on my linux box and it seems to be connecting fine with the Kafka broker and zookeeper as i don't see any errors in the logs and the jetty server seems to be running.

I am primarily wanting to test the consumer using the Kafka Rest proxy.

Hence i followed the documentation and created the consumer using the below rest url.

http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_test_consumer

It gives me back a 200 OK with a base URL that i can use to then subscribe to topics, so i use the base url and pass in an array of topics as suggested in the documentation, but it returns a 404 with the following response.

{"error_code":40403,"message":"Consumer instance not found."}

Answer (score 0):

@A_De I assume you followed the below 3 - step process for the consumption.

http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#quickstart

I assume you are running only one instance of Rest proxy. If not, you would have to make sure that subscripton goes back to the same node. Also, subscriptions are not persistent and would need to subsrive every time the Rest Proxy is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Kafka Rest configuration documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/config.html), an idle consumer will be destroyed after 30 seconds. This behavior can be controlled by the **consumer.instance.timeout.ms** property.

Comment: I just tested it and setting  consumer.instance.timeout.ms =1 on the POST consumer call does not produce a 404 on the subsequent subscription call on v2